# Extract multiple arrays from dataframe python

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, numpy

```
customer| current_state | year  | amount
ax111   |   A           |   3   |  300
ax112   |   D           |   4   |  4890
ax113   |   G           |   9   |  624
```

I have a dataframe, I need to extract the customers data into an array list, where the current state is the position where the amount needs to be placed.There are 7 states (A-G)

example output

```
([
    [300,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,4890,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,624],
])
```

I also need to extract year in a 1d array

`year=[3,4,9]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `MultiIndex` by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) for reshape and then add missing states by [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
states = list('ABCDEFG')
df1 = (df.set_index('current_state', append=True)['amount']
         .unstack(fill_value=0)
         .reindex(states, axis=1, fill_value=0))
print (df1)

current_state    A  B  C     D  E  F    G
0              300  0  0     0  0  0    0
1                0  0  0  4890  0  0    0
2                0  0  0     0  0  0  624
```

If logic is different and need pivoting per customers by [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) with aggregate `sum` if possible duplicated `custome, current_state` rows:

```
df1 = (df.pivot_table(index='customer',
                      columns='current_state', 
                      values='amount',
                      fill_value=0, 
                      aggfunc='sum')
         .reindex(states, axis=1, fill_value=0))
print (df1)
current_state    A  B  C     D  E  F    G
customer                                 
ax111          300  0  0     0  0  0    0
ax112            0  0  0  4890  0  0    0
ax113            0  0  0     0  0  0  624
```

Then convert to lists:

```
L = df1.to_numpy().tolist()
print (L)
[[300, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 4890, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 624]]

year = df['year'].tolist()
print (year)
[3, 4, 9]
```